# When stopping the spring application running on tomcat, It throws some warnings

Tags: spring, tomcat

I am working on a spring batch application, which is using a comboPooledDataSource to connect to the database. And the application is running on tomcat9.
When I stop the pod(container) to deploy another version of application, the logs shows that the application has been stoped, but before destroying the container it throws some warnings.

```
19-Aug-2020 09:58:16.235 WARNING [Thread-13] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [] appears to have started a thread named [Timer-0] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:552)
 java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
19-Aug-2020 09:58:16.235 WARNING [Thread-13] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [] appears to have started a thread named [C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[]-DeferredStatementDestroyerThread-#0] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:683)
19-Aug-2020 09:58:16.236 WARNING [Thread-13] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [] appears to have started a thread named [oracle.jdbc.driver.BlockSource.ThreadedCachingBlockSource.BlockReleaser] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 oracle.jdbc.driver.BlockSource$ThreadedCachingBlockSource$BlockReleaser.run(BlockSource.java:327)
19-Aug-2020 09:58:16.236 WARNING [Thread-13] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [] appears to have started a thread named [Resource Destroyer in BasicResourcePool.close()] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
 java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
 java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
 java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
 oracle.net.ns.Packet.receive(Packet.java:311)
 oracle.net.ns.DataPacket.receive(DataPacket.java:105)
 oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.getNextPacket(NetInputStream.java:305)
 oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:249)
 oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:171)
 oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:89)
 oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.readNextPacket(T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.java:123)
 oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.read(T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.java:79)
 oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngineStream.unmarshalUB1(T4CMAREngineStream.java:429)
 oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:397)
 oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:257)
 oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C7Ocommoncall.doOLOGOFF(T4C7Ocommoncall.java:59)
 oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logoff(T4CConnection.java:844)
 oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.close(PhysicalConnection.java:2498)
 com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection.close(NewPooledConnection.java:642)
 com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection.closeMaybeCheckedOut(NewPooledConnection.java:255)
 com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.destroyResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:622)
 com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$1DestroyResourceTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1076)
 com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.destroyResource(BasicResourcePool.java:1101)
 com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.destroyResource(BasicResourcePool.java:1062)
 com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$100(BasicResourcePool.java:44)
 com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$5.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1316)
19-Aug-2020 09:58:16.239 SEVERE [Thread-13] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@19931e16]) and a value of type [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext] (value [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@205f573e]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
```

I Have checked other related questions where it says
**
These are just warnings, tomcat has removed or stopped it forcibly.
**
But I want to make changes in my application. So that, no other warnings are to be shown from application design point of view.

Could anyone have any idea, what to check in the application and how to solve it.